# Hyperref multiline textbox reduce padding

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, textfield

I am trying to create a multiline textbox in a form that displays two lines of text. I defined a command `\mlinetextbox` and set the height of the textbox as a parameter. When I create a text box with these properties and set the height to `2\baselineskip`, there is padding at the top of the textbox which makes it display only one line, while the second line is partially cut-off.

New command definition:

```
\newcommand*{\mlinetxtbox}[2]{\TextField[name=#1, multiline=true, width=\linewidth, height=#2, charsize=11pt, bordercolor=red,backgroundcolor={}]{}}
```

Command usage: `\mlinetxtbox{ReasonForVisit}{2\baselineskip}`

Is there any parameter that can be adjusted to remove the top padding and make the textbox display both lines?

[image: Multiline textbox with and without padding]

Comment: No, it is the PDF viewer which decides how to place the text, hyperref has no control here. Use a larger height, something like `\dimexpr 2.3\baselineskip +2pt`  should work.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thank you so much for your response. I was thinking that there could be some missing parameters that could be used to reduce the top padding. It's good to know that the viewer also exerts its own control over features that are displayed in the PDF document.